# How to broadcast a new block

Tags: blockchain, block, broadcast

When i mine a new block on my pc, how can i broadcast it to other peers, making it included in the blockchain and getting my reward?

Is there any API that provides a function like "sendBlock" or something?

I'm asking it for bitcoin and any other criptocurrency. Ty

Comment: I'm not clear on your question... mining bitcoins with a PC is nearly impossible. Mining other coins might be possible, maybe you need a powerful graphics card. Then again, you wouldn't broadcast a block (manually). Instead you would run a software, that does specific calculations, and initiate the sending to other peers. Maybe have a look at how mining works, and come back to re-phrase (precise) your question?

Comment: Yes, i know that mining with a single pc is impossible, but i would learn how the sending to other peers works. I want to create a new software for mining, so i need to build the block myself and manually send it to the network.

Answer (score 2):

What i was looking for is `submitblock` RPC call.